# PHPExcel: Data is not exporting dynamically in columns after iterating for loop in php?

Tags: php, for-loop, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I am **exporting dynamic Columns data** is not exporting while iterating **for loop in phpexcel** or **spreadsheet** both i tried **not giving any error** also please check once as i am new here

```
     $inn_table = "";

        for($i=0;$i<count($labels);$i++) {
            if (isset($result['qualification']['dd1'])) {
            if($result['qualification']['dd1']!="") {
                $found=false;

                for($j=0;$j<count($dd1);$j++) {
                    $temp = explode(">",$dd1[$j]);    


                    if($temp[0]==$labels[$i]) {
                        $name = explode(">",$dd1[$j]);

                         $inn_table .= '<td>'.$name[1].'</td>'; //here i am trying to export data in columns

                    }
                }

            }
        }
}
   echo $inn_table;
```

Comment: sidenote: [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) last version, 1.8.1, was released in 2015. The project was officially deprecated in 2017 and permanently archived in 2019. The project has not be maintained for years and must not be used anymore. All users must migrate to its direct successor [PhpSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), or another alternative.

Comment: When you say it isn't exporting correctly, please explain what you need and what you are getting.

Comment: @jibsteroos i Already mentioned i tried in both PhpSpreadsheet and excel also only column data i need to print. or export which is not dependent on both

Comment: @NigelRen i need ` $inn_table .= '<td>'.$name[1].'</td>'` to be printed but nothing comes it exported as blank